# tailwind grid-cols now applying

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

My grid was working fine and without changing anything it stopped applying the grid-col classes (as you can see in the screen-shot only .grid class is applied and no grid-col classes) and now it is putting everything into 1 column only.

if I put `grid grid-cols-4` only it works, `grid grid-cols-2` or any other number of cols puts it into 1 column only.

[image]

```
<div className='grid gap-1 grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 xl:grid-cols-6'>{menus.map(renderMenuItem)}</div>
```

```
  function renderMenuItem(menu: MenuItem) {
    return <MenuButtonContainer key={menu.id} menu={menu} setEditMenu={showEditMenu} onSwipe={onSwipe} listView={listView} />;
  }
```

```
function MenuButtonContainer({ menu, listView, setEditMenu, onSwipe }: Props) {
  ...
  return <MenuGridButton ref={ref} menu={menu} bg={backgroundColor} events={events} hasFooter={hasFooter} />;
}
```

```
function MenuGridButton({ menu, bg, events, hasFooter }: Props, ref: LegacyRef<HTMLDivElement> | null) {
...
  return (
    <div key={menu.id}>
      hello
      {/* <MenuButton bg={bg} events={events}>
        <h4 className={getTextStyles()}>{menu.itemName}</h4>
        {hasFooter && <MenuButtonFooter {...menu} />}
      </MenuButton> */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

tailwind.config.js:

```
/* eslint-env node */
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');

module.exports = {
  content: ['./index.html', './src/components/**/*.{ts,tsx}', './src/assets/icon/*.{ts,tsx}', './src/styles/*.ts', './src/contexts/**/*.tsx'],
  theme: {
    screens: {
      xs: '481px',
      ...defaultTheme.screens,
      lx: { max: '1279px' },
      gl: { max: '1023px' },
      dm: { max: '767px' },
      ms: { max: '639px' },
      sx: { max: '480px' },
      tall: { raw: '(min-height: 800px and max-width: 639px)' }
    },
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        myriad: 'MyriadPro',
        myriadBold: 'MyriadProBold'
      },
      colors: {
        primary: '#0097D2',
        secondary: '#0085b9',
        tertiary: '#005174',
        primaryDark: '#009689',
        secondaryDark: '#06A3B1',
        primaryLight: '#1D6C87',
        secondaryLight: '#86DDFF',
        tertiaryLight: '#006086',
        textPrimary: '#00BEE3',
        textSecondary: '#1083a6',
        textTertiary: '#00729f',
        outline: '#39c7ff',
        info: '#8a6de9',
        success: '#33cd5f',
        error: '#D93600'
      },
      height: {
        px: '1px',
        13: '52px',
        15: '60px',
        18: '72px',
        19: '76px',
        26: '104px',
        38: '152px',
        300: '300px',
        350: '350px',
        400: '400px',
        450: '450px',
        500: '500px',
        '1/10': '10%',
        '3/10': '30%',
        '7/10': '70%',
        '9/10': '90%'
      },
      width: {
        px: '1px',
        13: '52px',
        15: '60px',
        18: '72px',
        22: '90px',
        35: '140px',
        38: '152px',
        300: '300px',
        350: '350px',
        400: '400px',
        450: '450px',
        500: '500px',
        550: '550px',
        600: '600px',
        700: '700px',
        '1/10': '10%',
        '3/10': '30%',
        '7/10': '70%',
        '9/10': '90%',
        '95%': '95%',
        '96%': '96%',
        '97%': '97%',
        '98%': '98%',
        '99%': '99%'
      },
      maxHeight: {
        500: '500px'
      },
      maxWidth: {
        screen: '100vw'
      },
      fontSize: {
        '1xl': '22px'
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: []
};
```